# How to make a two X axis tag chart in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I weight myself every morning, and been doing so for the last 2 years or so. I track my weight in a Google sheet, and the amount of data is large enough that I need to group it somehow. I have the following:

| Day | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 82,2 | 82,5 |
| 2 | 80,7 | 82,1 | 82,3 |
| 3 | 79 | 82,2 | 82,5 |
| 4 | 79,1 | 80,6 |  |
| 5 | 79,7 | 80,9 | 82,4 |
| 6 | 78,8 | 81,4 | 82,2 |
| 7 | 79 | 81,8 | 83,3 |
| 8 | 80 | 81,5 | 82,9 |

And so on. I would like to have a chart that plots in the X axis the combined tag o January 1, January 2, January 3... so that I can achieve something like this:

[image: chart]

So far, I achieved this by inputting the data in 2 columns like so:

| Day | Kg |
| --- | --- |
| 3January2022 | 75,3 |
| 4January2022 | 75,1 |
| 5January2022 | 75,1 |
| 6January2022 | 74,8 |
| 7January2022 | 74,8 |
| 8January2022 | 74,6 |
| 9January2022 | 74,2 |
| 10January2022 | 73,4 |

But the problem is, with 2 years in, the sheer amount of scrolling that I have to do to reach the bottom to input is huge.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JulianGR, I would say the structure of the second table is best practice to show the data that you need in the graph, there are many different approaches to make the data input process easier. You can use the shortcut "CRTL + Down Arrow" to get to the latest value added on column B (KG). you can also hide all rows that have already data so the empty rows are close to the headers, you can repeat this process regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to continue using the same table format you can use this Formula to get an "unpivoted" output:

```java
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(B1:M1&"-"&A2:A32&" "&B2:M32))," ")),"where Col1 > date '1990-1-1' and Col2 is not null")
```

1. This table (random data is used for this the example):

[image: Original Table]

2. Would be converted to two columns that can be used in your chart:

[image: Output]

The formula would add new values to the columns, you would still need to scroll down or use a [shortcut](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110) to get to the end of the column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not exactly what I was looking for, but I guess its not possible to do what I want. I'm still accepting it as resolved though, thanks again =)